# jQuery not posting all inputs of a form after the .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I have a form generated dynamically with the method .append() of jQuery.
I can add any number of new input, textbox, cmbbox, etc...

But the problem is that when I do the sumbit of the form, the PHP target does not receive the new input added, but just the vars connected to the input already in the form before the append().

Any ideas?

The javascript:

```
$("#button").live('click',function add(){
   $("#list").append(
       '<li style="height:20px;">'
    +'<input type="text" class="text" id="prova" name="prova[]" value="prova">'+ 
       '</li>'
   );
});
```

The Html:

```
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Add input">
<form name = "form" id="form" action="post.php" method="POST">
   <ul style="width:670px;padding:0px 0px 30px 0px" id="list">
   </ul>
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
  print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: The code work good, There was a problem in positioning of the tag <form> that was in a <div> and had to be outside

Comment: This comment is the key that led me to my repair. I had my `<form>` tag inside the `<tbody>` tag of the table to which I was `.append()` ing. Moved the `<form>` tag above the table and submit now includes the appended fields.

Comment: If the input is `disabled`, it will not be sent :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **Problem 1:**

Your `#button` should not be of type `submit`, since you just want to use it to add to the form and not submit the form. So you should have:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Add input">
```

### **Problem 2:**

You are overwriting your variables. The `name` is the variable sent with the form, so each `input` addition must have a new name, or the variable must be an array.

Additionally, you can't have more than one element with the same `id`.

The simplest way to solve this is to make `prova` an array by using the form `prova[]`:

```
$("#button").live('click',function() {
   $("#list").append(
       '<li style="height:20px;">' +
         // Removed repetitive ID and made prova an array
       '<input type="text" class="text" name="prova[]" value="prova"></li>'
   ); 
});
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XAZD7/)**

Comment: Same problem, it's like the DOM did not see the new items and the submit not send those variables.

Comment: @Claudio - It works. Take a look at this example ==> http://jsfiddle.net/XAZD7/ (click `add input` a few times, then `submit` - change the values in the inputs too if you want)

Comment: It works :) thank you, there was a problem in the tag <form> in the html (not in the posted code)

Answer (score 2):

You are intercepting the `click` event and adding elements to the form, but the event has already started, and will complete its default action (submit the form) without re-checking the content of the form.

You should stop the event after adding the fields (preventDefault should be the right choice), and then re-submit the form.

Something along these lines:

```
$('#button').live('click', function add(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#list').append(...);
    $('#form').submit();
});
```

I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty confident that it should work :)

Comment: Instead of using `preventDefault()`, it'd be much simpler to change the `type` of `#button` to `button` instead of `submit`. Also, this doesn't solve the multiple identical `name` s.... see my answer.

Comment: Also, why do you have a `$('#form').submit();` as the last line? That'll submit the form the first time `#button` is clicked... making `#button` pretty useless.

Comment: #button is outside the form, so it will submit  nothing.

Comment: Peter and Molle you're both right, I totally misread the question. Apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify, and putting any other problems aside, @Claudio's note is the correct answer here. I just had the same problem, button type was 'button' and the new element's name was being dynamically incremented. Everything looked fine, but the added elements *would not submit*.

Then I noticed my form tags were inside the table tags. I moved them outside and it all worked as planned.

Answer (score 0):

Have any code to show?  In order for php to "see" the vars submitted, you have to ensure that it has the "name" attribute specified on the form elements.  I have a feeling your issue is going to be with the jQuery not the php.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess: You haven't set name attributes for your dynamically added elements.

Comment: OP's code sets the `name` attributes, but they're all identical.