# Jquery append inputs not working

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a problem with the jquery append function.
I want to input a field for each number (got all that figured out)
The problem i am having is that the inputs get added (visually) to the page but won't be included in the $_POST vars in the PHP script.

It is not because of a misspelled name since i use `var_dump($_POST);` and it is not included there. It is also not because of a missing name attribute

I have read that you should append the the inputs to the actual form but i can't do that since they have to be inside of a specific div. i tried using `form#divname` but that doesn't seem to be working at all since it just doesn't append anything anymore, not even visually.

The div i am appending to is inside the `<form>`.

Code:

jQuery:

```
$("#group_"+grp+"_opts_div").append('
<input type="text" name="group_'+grp+'_'+i2+'" style="width:80px;" placeholder="Option name">
$<input type="text" name="group_'+grp+'_'+i2+'_extra" style="width:30px;" placeholder="Extra">
<input type="radio" name="group_'+grp+'_default" value="'+i2+'" />');
```

(excuse me if it's a bit messy)

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="?p=1" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="box" id="optionbox" style="display:none;">
<div id="groupsdiv"></div>
</div>
<hr /><input type="submit" value="Add product" class="button" name="addproduct" />
</form>
```

and PHP:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br />";
        ${$key} = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES); 
}
```

Video explaining what it does: http://youtu.be/eyzUeKi3ZAk

As you can see by the output, Product_option equals 2 (Yes, use options)
and product_optiongroups equals 3 (as in 3 groups)

Comment: Show us your code please, that's helpful for us to understand your problem.

Comment: `$("#group_"+grp+"_opts_div").append('<input type="text" name="group_'+grp+'_'+i2+'" style="width:80px;" placeholder="Option name">$<input type="text" name="group_'+grp+'_'+i2+'_extra" style="width:30px;" placeholder="Extra"><input type="radio" name="group_'+grp+'_default" value="'+i2+'" />');` (excuse me if it's a bit messy)

HTML:`<div id="groupsdiv"></div>
</div>
<hr /><input type="submit" value="Add product" class="button" name="addproduct" />
</form>`

Comment: Please edit your question and put this code up there.

Comment: Your HTML has a closing `</div>` that hasn't been opened, and you've got no `<form>` opening tag. And if you want to be excused for it 'being messy' *don't edit it back to being more messy*

Comment: Well the HTML code is cut out since i have a lot of code in the HTML but both the div and the form is opened above the cut.

Comment: Then, include all the relevant HTML - not broken snippets.  And please format it so we can read it easily, using indentation.

Comment: alright added the relevant html and (tried) to make it more read friendly.

Comment: you are trying to append it to a non-existant div id. you also have a rogue (extra) closing </div> tag.

Comment: as i said above, the scripts works fully as far as actually adding the fields  and it is visible. but the problem is it's not being included in the $_POST in the php

Comment: This looks weird, you are trying to append inputs to `#group_"+grp+"_opts_div`, which we can't see inside the form's HTML. Is there any reason for it? Assuming that div exists but outside the above form then of course they are not in POST request to backend.

Comment: the "+grp+" part is actually determined and appended by jquery, the problem isn't that the divs don't get appended, but it is that the inputs don't get included in the form

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847492/jquery-not-posting-all-inputs-of-a-form-after-the-append and check your html. I had a similar problem and found that having the `<form>` tag inside the `<tbody>` tag of the table to which I was `.append()`ing somehow was interfering with the browser attaching the inputs to the form. Moved the `<form>` tag above the `<table>` tag and things started working.